# Convergence of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^{-1}+x}}}{\sqrt{x\phantom{|}}\sqrt{x^{-1}+x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

I've been trying to evauluate this integral
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^{-1}+x}}}{\sqrt{x\phantom{|}}\sqrt{x^{-1}+x}}dx$$

So far I have tried the substitution $$t =1/x +x$$ But this has made the integral more complicated. Also I am unsure of the limit of the function inside the integral as $x$ approaches zero.

Does the integral converge?

Comment: The integral does not converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the infinity it behaves as 
$$
\frac{x^{3/4}}{x},
$$
hence the integral diverges.

Comment: $\frac{x^{1/2}}{x}$?